# How to access object property in module.exports

Tags: javascript, object, express, javascript-objects

I am curious about how to access another object property in module.exports.

**here is the case :**

```js
module.exports = {

    text: 'abcd',
    index: (req, res)=>{
    console.log(text) <-- is not defined
    console.log(this.text) <-- undefined
    }
}
```

> well then, how to access the text property? thanks guys need your explanation.

Comment: It still surprises me how someone can learn about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) without learning about [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: the best practice to learn it by found case while coding :D thanks for reminding me. @FelixKling

Comment: Stack overflow does not work well when you edit your question to make it an entirely different question.  Your original question contain arrow syntax for the definition of `index` which is what I answered.  When you edited your question AFTER I wrote my answer, you kind of ruined the whole point of this question/answer.  Please do NOT do that.  I'd suggest you put your question back the way you originally asked it so the answers are still relevant.  If you want to ask for some further info, you can either see if you can get that info via comments or you should ask a new/different question.

Comment: well thank you for informing me, ive got it back @jfriend00

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Javascript does not have a built-in way to refer to other properties in the same object. There are good reasons why it cannot do this for any arbitrary property.  So, you either have to make sure that `this` has the right object value in it or you need to save the appropriate object reference yourself somewhere that you can get to it.

Here's a way where you save the object reference yourself which works fine for a singleton object:

```
let myObj = {

 text: 'abcd',
 index: (req, res)=>{
   console.log(myObj.text)
 }

}

module.exports = myObj;
```

---

If you know that `.index()` will always be called appropriately as a method on your `module.exports` (which would be the usual case), then you can stop using the `=>` definition and use a normal `function` definition (which should pretty much always be used for method declarations) and then `this` will have the desired value.

```
module.exports = {

 text: 'abcd',
 index: function(req, res) {
   console.log(this.text)
 }
}
```

This will work as long as `.index()` index is called like this:

```
let myModule = require('myModule');
myModule.index(req, res);
```

People tend to fall in love with the arrow syntax and forget that it should pretty much NEVER be used for method definitions because it does NOT set `this` to the host object which creates problems for methods.  Instead, use the regular `function` definition for methods of an object.

---

Arrow functions are typically very useful for callback functions where you want the callback to have access to the `this` value from your environment (called the lexical value of `this`).  Here are some useful examples:

```
class Timer {
    delay(t, cb) {
       this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
           // preserve this value inside a callback
           this.timer = null;
           cb();
       })
    }
}
```

Or

```
// preserve this value inside a callback
let filtered = myArray.filter(item => {
    return item.id !== this.master.id;
});
```

---

On the other hand, you pretty much never want to use an arrow declaration for a method because that will override the usual object value for `this` and replace it with a lexical value for `this`.

Comment: Good explanation but I wanted to know in what all scenorio we can use arrow notation? Thanks :)

Comment: how about
`module.exports = {

  index(){
    this.text cannot have the desired value.
  }
}`

im using es6 syntax

Comment: @ricky - Arrow functions are explicitly for when you want the `this` value to be lexical and not determined from how the function was called.  In your case, the lexical value of this is whatever `this` is at the top level of your module, it is not your object.  You can think of the lexical this as what was the value of `this` when this code was defined.  That is simply not what you want, therefore the arrow syntax is not appropriate.  The arrow syntax is often quite appropriate when specify callback functions where you want to keep the lexical value of `this` inside the callback.

Comment: @ricky - I added a few arrow function examples to my answer.  Arrow functions are NOT just a syntactical shortcut that should be used all the time.  You need to know the difference between a function declared with the arrow syntax and one declared with the normal function syntax in order to know which one is appropriate.  If you're really not sure which to use, then you probably should stick with the regular `function` declaration (which we all made work just fine for many years with ES5 and earlier).  The arrow syntax is useful when you know what you're doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
module.exports = {

        text: 'abcd',
        index: function (req,res) {
            console.log(this.text)
        }
    }
```

accessing via

```
var te=require('modulename')
    te.index()
```